# nginx reverse proxy loop

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I need to:

1. point site.com to my site.github.io (that works)
2. point site.com/anything to filesystem /site/dist (that works)
3. point site2.com to site.com to filesystem /root/dist (that doesn't work, here it shows site.github.io)

site.com.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.com;

    location = / {
        proxy_pass              http://site.github.io;
        proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $remote_addr;
    }

    location / {
        root /site/dist;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

site2.com.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site2.com;

    proxy_set_header Host site.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/$request_uri;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case http://site2.com you're going to end up with uri = "/" when hitting site.com, which you have set to proxy to site.github.io.

You may want to do instead for site2 is:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/site2/$request_uri;
}
```

Then in site.com:

```
location ~ ^/site2(.*)$ {
   root /site/dist;
   try_files $1 /index.html;
}
```

OR

```
location /site2 {
    rewrite ^/site2(.*)$ $1 break;
    root /site/dist;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```